# Git automatically merge release branch to master after any release

Tags: java, git, jenkins, bitbucket, branch

Is there any feature/plugin or settings in bitbucket or jenkins to automatically merge the release branch into master after each release?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bitbucket Cloud or Bitbucket Server?

Comment: Bitbucket Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a job and use [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/) you can trigger that job on tags being pushed to Bitbucket. There are examples here:

- Bitbucket Cloud: https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/blob/master/src/test/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gwt/bdd/bitbucket-cloud/bitbucket-cloud-tag.feature
- Bitbucket Server: https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin/blob/master/src/test/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/gwt/bdd/bitbucket-server/bitbucket-server-tag.feature

Having the tag name contributed to the build as a variable, you can have a pipeline script that merges that `tag` to `master`. If not all tags created are releases, you can use the plugins filter feature to filter out tags with a certain pattern.

```
node {
 sh """
  git clone ...
  git checkout master
  git merge $theVariableContainingTagNameYouConfigured
 """
}
```